# Short book involving a car crash and artificial humans

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I read this book several years ago and can't remember the title. The protagonist was a girl who was in a car accident. After the accident, her family moves to a new, secluded neighborhood, where she goes to meetings/a support group of some sort. She later discovers that she died in the accident and her mind was saved...in...something.... I *think* the cover was white with a blue butterfly...but I'm not sure. It was something of that color scheme. I'm fairly certain it was published after 2005. Does anyone know the name of this book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[The Adoration of Jenna Fox](http://www.slimekids.com/book-trailers/letter-a/the-adoration-of-jenna-fox.html)* by Mary E. Pearson. (2008) ([various covers](http://www.librarything.com/work/4448913/covers))

> Who is Jenna Fox? Seventeen-year-old Jenna has been told that is her name. She has just awoken from a coma, they tell her, and she is still recovering from a terrible accident in which she was involved a year ago. But what happened before that? Jenna doesn't remember her life. Or does she? And are the memories really hers?
>
> Jenna slowly begins to recognize that a secret is being kept from her and something complex and dangerous is going on. As she realizes that she essentially died in the infamous "accident" and was reborn through her father's controversial discovery.

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I knew her name was something like Jenny or Jennifer...