# Book about young girl who got injured and was remade in a robot body without her knowledge?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, robots

I haven't read this book in years and can't remember the name of the book. It wasn't popular or anything but I remember bits and pieces.

She was a young girl and she noticed things weren't right when she woke up from her accident the biggest was she was taller now (turns out her mother had her robot body made taller so she could be a dancer) her grandma didn't like the new her and was horrible to her. She lived in this private school or something?

They saved a few of her eggs so she could have a kid which I think she did. In the second book she helped some other girl in some adventure and like a bunch of years had passed like hundreds of years because she's a robot she's still alive. Anyway the future America was split half-Republican and half-Democratic.

I wanna say her last name was Fox but I can't remember I also feel like her first name started with a J but I can't be certain.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152759/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: not putting this as an answer because I'm not sure of the procedure for duplicates. Adoration of Jenna Fox, also the answer for this question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96687/existential-book-about-girl-resurrected-by-nanotechnology/96707#96707 and this one http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80103/short-book-involving-a-car-crash-and-artificial-humans/80114#80114

Comment: @NiceOrc, the procedure is: 1) post your answer, 2) if the answer is accepted or there is a comment from the OP indicating correctness then it can be closed as a duplicate. Definitely post your answer, though -- seems likely to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment above by NiceOrc this is likely *[The Adoration of Jenna Fox](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1902241.The_Adoration_of_Jenna_Fox)*, published in 2008 by Mary E. Pearson, as answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96687/existential-book-about-girl-resurrected-by-nanotechnology) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80103/short-book-involving-a-car-crash-and-artificial-humans). I think the review [here](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/40836801?book_show_action=true) provides a better summary:

> Jenna is the miracle child, her parents' angel, the perfect child who excels while inside she silently protests, only to show minor rebellions at sixteen. After a horrific accident and a year in a coma, Jenna wakes in an old house in another state, with no memory of herself or what happened. She recovers quickly, but wonders endlessly about who she is. There is only her mother and her grandmother, Lily, in the big old house that they moved to from Boston, and Lily doesn't seem to like her at all. She speaks of Jenna like she's another person, somewhere else.
>
> As Jenna navigates her way through the act of living, watching old movies of Jenna growing up while snippets of memory slowly surface, her questions only grow. Why can't she walk properly, why don't her hands interlace? Why is the scar under her chin missing? Why is her mother so frightened, so controlling? Why must she hide from the world?

> The truth is staggering and frightening: her entire body is synthetic, and only ten per cent of her brain is from the pre-accident Jenna. She a lab project of her father's, a billionaire doctor who invented Bio Gel, in which organs can be housed indefinitely if kept at the right temperature. Too cold and Jenna will expire. Kept at a moderate temperature, and she could live hundreds of years, never visibly ageing. The implications are profound. Is she the real Jenna? Is ten per cent enough? Was she ever enough for her parents? Is it even ethical for her to be alive? And what makes Jenna dangerous is the fact that she's illegal, and shouldn't even exist.

Comment: [spoiler tag] The dad sounds like a dick